# PCRE regular expression match the first letter of a string

Tags: regex, mongodb, pcre

Could you point me out a PCRE RegEx that would match only the first letter of a string. I need to pass to Mongo DB, I'm concerning about performances at the moment I'm using `^a`.

Examples:

**MATCH**

apple

alligator

**NO MATCH**

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are special tokens in PCRE to represent beginning and end of a string

```
/^a/ => will match all strings that start with "a"
```

Comment: This solved the problem, I was not aware about the special token. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a start of string [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`.

```
^a
```